# NSAlert and NSWindow from NSTimer on El Capitan (10.11)

Tags: cocoa, osx-elcapitan

After updating to El Capitan all our NSAlerts and NSWindows presented from NSTimer functions are completely white (some reports of completely black, but I don't trust those 100%). No titlebar, no buttons, no text, just a completely white rectangle. The buttons are there though, if you click in the correct spot they go away.

In a function called from the NSTimer I do either:

```
  MyWindow* wp = [[MyWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:osr
                                      styleMask:styl
                                        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                          defer:YES];
  ...
  [wp orderFront:nil];
  ...
  [NSApp runModalForWindow:wp];
```

Or

```
  alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:nil defaultButton:nil alternateButton:nil otherButton:nil informativeTextWithFormat:@"%@",ns];

  [alert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];
  [alert setIcon:...];

  switch ([alert runModal]) {
```

The same code has worked as expected for many years and versions of OS X. And when run from "sendMessage" (i.e. user interaction) it still works. And yes, it's all on the main thread.

Anybody have some idea how to solve this?

Comment: You must be doing something more than running it from a timer. I can't reproduce this myself.

Comment: Such as, this works: 
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(t:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void)t:(id)s {
   NSAlert *a = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [a runModal];
}